# How to config IIS to run .net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

1- On visual studio 2019 and .net core 2.2, created a default web application and didn't change any thing on my project, just publish it.

2- Installed the same version of the run-time from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral) and put publish folder on the IIS (Windows 10 X64 enterprise), port 5000.

3- On the IIS changed CLR version to "No Managed Code" and brows website but I got this error message:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data 
 for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?  \C:\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:5000/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

After looking for this error code "Error Code     0x8007000d" on [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage) I do not know what's the problem.
Should I set a config or what?

Edited:
 This application works fine on visual studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [.NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.5-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) and simply refresh your page. The error is caused because AspNetCoreModule is not installed in your PC.

You can read more about ASP.NET Core Module [here](http://spnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 3):

To Host .net core app to IIS, Below are the checklist which I managed to resolve

- install .net core bundle (below 2.2 v1) and (3.0 and above v2)

  - Sometime when x86 and x64 .net core version may make problem
      that time in visual studio you can't choose .net core version even after installing particular version

    - To resolve this i usually uninstall all versions and work with x64 version of .net core runtime
- Restart the iis `"net stop was /y"`
  then `"net start w3svc"`
- After installing go and check in IIS
  Modules you can able to see v1 and v2
- Create an application pool
  with no managed clr version (.net core app). For framework app use (v4.0)
- In program.cs use "UseIISIntegration()"

> error

```
Application 'C:\TestCoreApp\' failed to start. Exception message:
Could not find dotnet.exe at 'C:\TestCoreApp\dotnet.exe' or
using the system PATH environment variable. Check that 
a valid path to dotnet is on the PATH and 
the bitness of dotnet matches the bitness of the IIS worker process.
```

> in web config change **processPath="C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"** from **processPath="dotnet.exe"** or add
>   path to environment variable

cross check below in config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\Webpi.test.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

> error :

```
Unable to load 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\3.1.0\hostfxr.dll'. This might be caused by a bitness mismatch between IIS application pool and published application.
```

> solution

check whether your application pool has "No Managed code" in .net clr version enter code here`